# Should I reveal real location of events in my book?

Tags: plot, setting

I wrote a non-released-yet adventure/sf book, in which events take place in a real city I know (actually, this is where I grew up). Most of the places I mentioned there are real, except only for those, which are obviously not (eg. underground ancient laboratory of an advanced race). There are no real people or businesses etc. mentioned at all.

For now I decided not to reveal the location. I used only general wording, like "the city" and "the castle".

What would be the benefits and drawbacks of revealing the real location of events? Keeping also in mind, that events of next parts will most likely take place in places I never been to (what may or may not be an issue).

Comment: Why don't you want to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it better to make clear immediately in which country/continent the story is taking place?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/8153/is-it-better-to-make-clear-immediately-in-which-country-continent-the-story-is-t)

Comment: @Allan, The core reason is that I plan to move the action all around the world and I will be writing about places I've never been to. I won't be able to describe them as accurately as the first one. I'm also worried about mistakes I may make regarding specific places, which may annoy people famkliar with the location. But on the other hand, the locations themselves will play role in the story.

Comment: It depends a lot on what's happening in the story. If there are any references to things like politics and social issues, then it matters where it's set because readers need to know how to situate it (eg LGBT characters or issues around race vary even between US cities, or things like the education system, police, and healthcare, as well as wars and elections). But you could e.g. set it in a fictional city that's a lot like a real one.